# Need help on replace method

Tags: javascript, regex

What does the following code do?please explain line by line.

```
 x="c_name";
 y=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```

if only x.replace(/^\s/)  was  given the replace method would replace the space character found in the beginning of string.But what those addition argument mean/are?
Does "|" mean "or" in replace method?please explain line by line

Comment: "starts with space" OR "ends with space", both greedy and global!

Comment: It looks like the trim function.

Answer (score 0):

```
 y=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
```

means the following:

- [Either (`|`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

  - match [one or more (`+`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) whitespace in the beginning of the string (`^\s+`)
  - or one or more whitespace characters at the end of the string (`\s+$`)

and replace them with nothing.

The `g` flag means it replaces all matches, and not just the first one.

That is, it trims whitespace off of the start and end of the string.

Comment: But after spacifying quantifies what is the use of specifying "/g" modifier.

Comment: @Maizere: What if there's whitespace both at the beginning and end? Then each of the two needs a separate match to replace it.

Comment: …that, after replacing (removing) whitespaces in the beginning, it goes on trying to match again (and find whitespaces in the end)

Comment: @Sebastian Paaske Tørhol Thank u si.

Comment: @Bergi I understand tht but i heard quentifier allow the replace/match method to serch the character only at the beginning ,i m right on this?

Answer (score 0):

It removes any number of space at start or end of the string.

It can be read as

- `^\s+` : some spaces at start
- `|` : or
- `\s+$` : some spaces at end
- `g` : all of them

See [the MDN documentation on regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

It's probably in your code because some old browsers (IE8-) don't have the [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function.

Comment: .Thank u a lot sir.But what is the use of specifying /g modifier after specifying quentifier in pattern

Comment: It means "global match" (not just the first match). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: thank u for the link.Cant we use "and" instead of "or" in replace method

Comment: what do you mean ? you could simply remove the `|`.

Comment: i mean cant we simply replace "|" with "or" keyword

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> `^` - Matches beginning of input.
>   `\s` - Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form feed, line feed and other unicode spaces.
>   `x|y` - Matches either x or y.
>   `+` - Matches the preceding item 1 or more times.
>   `$` - Matches end of input.

So it's basically a [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) function for older browsers.